# C#: Set directory's owner and propagate the changes

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

I'm setting a directory's owner via C#:

```
var acl = new DirectorySecurity(path, AccessControlSections.Owner);
acl.SetOwner("domain\username");
Directory.SetAccessControl(path, acl);
```

This works well, except for one thing: It doesn't propagate to child folders.
Is there a way to make this change propagate, except for recursively iterating through all subfolders and files and manually setting the owner?

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510565/changing-permissions-on-child-folders-in-c-sharp

Comment: there are the propagation flags, to be defined on a `FileSystemAccessRule` instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822318/1132334

Comment: @dlatikay - I know about the propagation flags of a FileSystemAccessRule, but I'm not trying to set an access rule: I'm trying to set ownership.